# Can I display other storyboard scenes inside a table cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accordion

I am trying to implement an accordion-styled table that is structured as below

Title 1

---

Main 1(hidden, unhide if Title 1 pressed)

---

Title 2

---

Main 2(hidden, unhide if Title 2 pressed)

---

Title 3

---

Main 3(hidden, unhide if Title 3 pressed)

---

I got the structures ready, but I need to display three different scenes that I created on the storyboard inside the cells Main 1,2,3 respectively. Is there a way I could implement this, or should I take a totally different approach to implement that?

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with ContainerView and Storyboard References
[image]

[image]

> **Programmatically:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

let vc = ViewController.fromStoryboard
addChildViewController(vc)
container.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

> **Storyboard**
>   [image]